# Managing duplicates photos & videos in both Google Drive & Google Photos?

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

The relatively recent divorce between Drive & Photos still has me a bit confused. Though to be honest, I was never really sure of this question: Before the changes, when I shared a Drive folder with Photos did that import & copy photos, duplicating & doubling the storage requirements?

I have about 40GB of photos & videos in Drive that seem to show up in Photos as well, and I suspect I might be getting double "charged" on the storage against my quota.

Now that the two seem completely disconnected from each other, can I delete photos in my Drive that are also in Photos without it deleting the copy in Photos?

Answer (score 0):

Before the change, the two were synced, and storage was not duplicated. I believe that storage of old photos is not duplicated after the change—the files are separate copies, and you can delete the copy in Drive without the copy in Photos being deleted now.

Storage of new photos after the change, when copied from Drive to Photos, is duplicated.